# phpUnit - File/Iterator/Autoload.php failed opening

Tags: phpunit, fatal-error

I am trying to get `phpUnit` running on a centos running plesk pannel.

I have installed phpunit successfully.

```
Package            Version State
File_Iterator      1.3.1   stable
PHPUnit            3.6.10  stable
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.1   stable
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.2   stable
PHP_Invoker        1.1.0   stable
PHP_Timer          1.0.2   stable
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.3   stable
Text_Template      1.1.1   stable
```

however whenever i run the phpunit command from the shell i get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45
>   PHP Fatal error: 
>   require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:') in /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45

Has anyone a clue how to solve the problem?

Comment: What does `pear info phpunit/File_Iterator` say? It looks like it didn't get installed, but PHPUnit depends on it.

Comment: On my Mac OSX 10.7.1 in /etc/php.ini the include_path was set to /user/lib/php/pear instead of /usr/lib/php/pear   It is surprising how long you can stare at something and not notice the extra e !

Comment: I do believe this is the correct answer to any questions relating to php unit File_Iterator. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator

Answer (score 6):

I tried a billion different articles and the commands that finally fixed this issue for me were the following:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/phpunit
```

Then, when I ran `phpunit`, I didn't get the errors and it ran successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how this translates for plesk, but the problem is the include_path specified in your php.ini file is set to just the current directory. Verify where your php.ini file is by running the following from the command line...

```
% php --info
```

...and look for the following entries...

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc

Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini

In this case, edit /etc/php.ini and look for the for include_path. In my case I need to set it as follows...

```
include_path = ".:/opt/php-5.3.14/lib/php/pear"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your include path must include the directory where PEAR installs all those packages. Add `/usr/share/pear` to your include path in `php.ini`--probably `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

On the Ubuntu (10.04) I also added `/usr/share/php` to the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora release 19 it has been solved by adding the **/usr/share/pear/** path to the **include_path** of **/etc/php.ini**